# Quotient space $\Bbb{Z}/2=\{\pm 1\}$?

Tags: group-theory, quotient-spaces

The reference (1) below defines a quotient space between two groups as:
$$V/W=\{v+W| v \in V\}$$
where $v+W$ is a coset. Reference (2) however writes that:
$$ \Bbb{Z}/2=\{\pm 1\}$$
I cannot see where this comes from (the reference does not define the multiplication operator). Can anyone help me out?

**References**

(1) http://www.math.northwestern.edu/~scanez/courses/334/notes/quotient-spaces.pdf

(2) https://www.dpmms.cam.ac.uk/~sjw47/RepThLectures.pdf (pg2)

Comment: It's $\Bbb{Z}/2\Bbb{Z}$. Do you see why it only has two elements?

Comment: @matboy ok so what is $\{\pm 1\}$ actually referring to then? The elements of one of the cosets or is $1$ one coset and $-1$ the other?

Comment: $\{\pm 1\}$ is the two element group, whose law is multiplication.

Comment: Here the notation $=$ is abusive : it's rather an isomorphism, that is $\Bbb{Z}/2\Bbb{Z}$ is isomorphic with the multiplicative group $\{1, -1\}$. But it is definitely not an equality